How to find root cause for myapge.com didn't send any data?
I have deployed my app on REDHAT server,behind LB in public cloud. SSL termination should be done on LB.
I got
The page is not working
myapge.com didn't send any data
I tried
curl 10.111.123.6:2273
failed to connect to 10.111.123.6 port 443 after 27071ms: Couldn't connect to server 

If I go for
nc -zv 10.111.123.6
Connection refused

How to check this? I am in a private cloud.
